# Determine where a page came from (what is the the referer is) using .net 5

Tags: .net-core, .net-5, referrer

Excuse me if this is answered elsewhere. I've looked and I see what appears should answer and I can't make it work for various reasons.

We have a modal that pops up when the user comes to our sight. We want it to only appear once. If the user navigates to it from within the site we don't want it to appear, if the user comes into it from outside of the site we want it to appear. It's essentially a disclaimer.

We are using .Net core 5. I see this question answered several times from posts years back but evidently Microsoft has changed how this is handled through the years as I haven't been able to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

As with most things - the answer was simple and right before me.

The answer is `Request.Headers["referer"];`

This either returns a null (coming in as starting page) or the URL that it is coming from. If it's a null or not equal to either localhost or site URL it is the first time coming into the site and I display the modal. If it is either localhost or the site URL I don't display the modal.

```
string Referer = Request.Headers["referer"];
```